# Dictionary with array of different data types as value

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to create a Dictionary with array of integer, string and boolean data types as values. I figured, I should use object[] as value, so declaration would look so:

```
Dictionary<long, object[]> netObjectArray = new Dictionary<long, object[]>();
```

Whenever I try setting its element's value to something, VS says there was no such key found in the dictionary.

```
netObjectArray[key][2] = val; // ex: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

How do I work with this correctly?

**UPD1:**
Somehow, right before throwing this exception, the other dictionary is used without problems in a similar way:

```
Dictionary<long, Vector2> netPositions = new Dictionary<long, Vector2>();
netPositions[key] = new Vector2(x, y); // works ok
```

After this locals show the value was assigned and dictionary now contains that entry. Why is this not the case with my other dictionary?

**Solution:** Before writing a value to an array of values, we must first initialize that array. This code works for me:

```
try { netObjectArray[key] = netObjectArray[key]; } // if the object is undefined,
catch { netObjectArray[key] = new object[123]; } // this part will create an object
netObjectArray[key][0] = new Vector2(x, y) as object; // and now we can assign a value to it :)
```

Comment: Have you initialized `netObjectArray[key]` to at least `new object[2]`?

Comment: Besides, storing different types like this in a Dictionary is a bad code smell. Do you really need that, or can you encapsulate the data in a better format?

Comment: You could use a `Tuple<int,string,bool>` as value instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: I'm making a multiplayer game, where each player has lots of different types of parameters including coordinates, health, username, bullets, all that stuff. If you can propose an easier way of accessing all that data in similar fashion, please do.

Comment: That would be a separate question, and if we are talking about the storage mechanism in general I would try [programmers.se] or more appropriate [gamedev.se].

Comment: @user1306322 Create a `Player` class with all of that info, and have a Dictionary of `Player`s.

Comment: @Servy I wish I could upvote your comment multiple times: this is precisely the case when arrays are bad and classes are excellent.

Comment: @user1306322, It looks like different kind of things used for different things in your code. Don't put them in a dictionary at all, put them as properties in a regular class.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo Each iteration will then collect data from different sources, I don't think that would work faster or look better in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dictionary<long, object[]> netObjectArray = new Dictionary<long, object[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) netObjectArray[i] = new object[100];//This is what you're missing.
netObjectArray[key][2] = val;
```

Comment: Can you explain why am I missing it in the array dictionary and the usual dictionary works fine without it?

Comment: My guess is: In your `Dictionary<long, Vector2>` you're putting a `Vector2` in `netPositions[key]`, which is what you're supposed to do. In `Dictionary<long, object[]>` you're _not_ putting an `object[]` in `netObjectArray[key]` (which is what you're supposed to do) at all. You're skipping a step. You're trying to access a nonexistent `object[]`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to write a value to previously undefined array of said values. Good eye.

Comment: @user1306322 Assuming I understand correctly that the `long` is the player-number and that you now want to 'initialize' a new player: Add: `long numberOfPlayers = 0;` somewhere. And then: `void AddPlayer() { netObjectArray[numberOfPlayers++] = new object[100]; }//Note: numberOfPlayers will only be increased after the action. As needed.`

Comment: @user1306322 But I would actually advise going with [Servy's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095835/dictionary-with-array-of-different-data-types-as-value#comment12931694_10095835) advice of creating a class for each player's 'properties'.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected: if the key is not present in the `Dictionary<K,V>`, an attempt to read at that key fails. You should assign an empty array to the element at the `key` before accessing it.

Here is the typical pattern of accessing a dictionary when you do not know if the key is present or not:

```
object[] data;
if (!netObjectArray.TryGetValue(key, out data)) {
    data = new object[MyObjCount];
    netObjectArray.Add(key, data);
}
data[2] = val;
```

**EDIT** (in response to the edit of the question)

You see an exception only when you try reading the dictionary at the previously unknown key. Assignments such as yours

```
netPositions[key] = new Vector2(x, y);
```

are allowed, even though the key is not in the dictionary at the time of the assignment: this performs an "insert or update" operation on your dictionary.

Comment: Then how does `netPositions[key] = new Vector2(x, y);` not cause exception, while `netObjectArray[key][2] = val;` which goes right next, does? Is it the `new` part which is allowed and simply setting is not?

Comment: @user1306322 Please see my edit. Essentially, reading an unknown key is not allowed, but writing an unknown key is OK.

Comment: My comment was response to your edit. As I understand, I'm writing consecutively to two previously undefined values. You are saying to have that exception thrown, I need to try reading an undefined value at selected position, but I am not doing it anywhere in the code. **ok, false alarm** the answer is in the comment below [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095835/dictionary-with-array-of-different-data-types-as-value/10095939#comment12932296_10095939]

Comment: @user1306322 You do perform a read, but in an obscure way: `netObjectArray[key][2] = val` is equivalent to `(netObjectArray[key])[2] = val`, and the `netObjectArray[key]` is an attempt to read an array of objects at the `key`. The write part of the assignment operation goes against the object array that you fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, object[]> complex = new Dictionary<string, object[]>();

complex.Add("1", new object[] { 1, 2 });

object[] value = complex["1"];
value[1] = val;
```

works for me...